# SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync doesn't find anything

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to find all `PropertyChangedEventHandler` events in my solution, and then find all listeners added to those events. But I can't seem to get a list of the events.

This is all the code in the solution being analyzed:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RoslynTarget
{
    public class Example : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

        public void DoNothing() { }
    }
}
```

And this is my code for analyzing it. `references.Count == 1` and `r.Locations.Count == 0`, but exactly one location should be found. What's going on here?

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FindSymbols;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace RoslynTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string solutionPath = @"C:\Users\<user>\Code\RoslynTarget\RoslynTarget.sln";
            const string projectName = "RoslynTarget";

            var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CheckForSystemRuntimeDependency", "true" } });
            var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;

            var project =
                solution.Projects
                    .Where(proj => proj.Name == projectName)
                    .First();

            var compilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
            var eventType = compilation.ResolveType("System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler").First();
            var references = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(eventType, solution).Result;

            foreach (var r in references)
            {
                foreach (var loc in r.Locations)
                {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Extensions.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;

namespace RoslynTest
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<INamedTypeSymbol> ResolveType(this Compilation compilation, string classFullName)
        {
            return new IAssemblySymbol[] { compilation.Assembly }
                .Concat(compilation.References
                    .Select(compilation.GetAssemblyOrModuleSymbol)
                    .OfType<IAssemblySymbol>())
                .Select(asm => asm.GetTypeByMetadataName(classFullName))
                .Where(cls => cls != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Roslyn expert (and I don't play one on TV), but I dont think the event declaration is a variable is it?  Wouldn't it be an `EventDeclaration`?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Although I removed that code as irrelevant to the question, this is important for anyone trying to do anything similar: `EventDeclarationSyntax` is for property-like events; `EventFieldDeclarationSyntax` is for field-like events; fields (including events) apparently contain multiple variables, and are not capable of being resolved as their composite selves. See http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compilation/SyntaxTreeSemanticModel.cs,1257

Comment: Note: calling GetTypeByMetadataName does more or less what your Extensions.cs is doing. You shouldn't need to write that.

Comment: `GetTypeByMetadataName` is not a general solution to the problem, so until something more appropriate is released I'll keep my extension method.

Comment: Why is the Compilation one not sufficient for your needs? It's doing what your extension is doing, as far as I can tell.

Comment: And also a general thing to check for problems like this: on the compilation you're searching, call GetDiagnostics() and verify that there isn't something else that's causing that project to fail to load correctly. If something is, then it could mean semantics are very broken for the project and all bets are off.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski `GetTypeByMetadataName` doesn't allow me to know for sure whether I'm running into this problem: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3864

Comment: You'd know that by checking GetDiagnostics().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently I've done similar thing where I was trying to find the reference of a method in complete solution.
To use `FindReferenceAsync` you have create symantic model first and find the symbol from there. Once you have the symbol you can use the `FindReferenceAsync`.

Here's the snippet that I used and it's working:

```
var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
{
    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
    {
        var model = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;

        var methodInvocation = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;
        InvocationExpressionSyntax node = null;
        try
        {
            node = methodInvocation.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()
             .Where(x => ((MemberAccessExpressionSyntax)x.Expression).Name.ToString() == methodName).FirstOrDefault();

            if (node == null)
                continue;
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            // Swallow the exception of type cast. 
            // Could be avoided by a better filtering on above linq.
            continue;
        }

        methodSymbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol;
        found = true;
        break;
    }

    if (found) break;
}

foreach (var item in SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(methodSymbol, solution).Result)
{
    foreach (var location in item.Locations)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Project Assembly -> {0}", location.Document.Project.AssemblyName);
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

}
```

Here's the [complete working code](https://gist.github.com/vendettamit/5a1a71eba84c741b397a#file-referencefinder-cs). If you want to visualize the Roslyn tree then you can try using [Roslyn tree visualizer](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Syntax%20Visualizer) to see code structuring.

#### Update

As per discussion in comments with OP Installing [Roslyn SDK](https://aka.ms/roslynsdktemplates) fixed the issue. Assuming that there might be some updates in SDK to generate Symbols information as compared to Nuget dlls when using `GetCompilationAsync`.

Comment: +1 for the Roslyn tree visualizer, that thing is incredibly helpful when I've tried to figure out how to parse some bit of code.

Comment: I don't understand how this can be done with an external type... I don't get the type symbol from a document (or a document's model), because it's external.

Comment: I only shared the core of the program. This program is to find type/references in a given solution which mean it will be external. Did you look at the complete source code? https://gist.github.com/vendettamit/5a1a71eba84c741b397a#file-referencefinder-cs If you look at it carefully there's only thing which is different from your approach is the way this program is finding symbol.

Comment: In this program I was trying to find a Method invocations in complete solution. You might have to tweat it a little which is why I suggested the RoslynTreeVisualizer. It will come handy for sure.

Comment: I hadn't looked at the gist, but it looks substantially the same, for my purposes, as your code here (which is a good thing). I'm installing the Roslyn SDK now; +1 for the recommendation, but I'll probably end up accepting my own answer.

Comment: Huh. Installing the Roslyn SDK seems to have knocked something loose and now my original code works. So you get the answer after all, I guess.

Comment: Per http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312783/problem-was-solved-almost-accidentally-by-a-suggestion-in-an-answer/312785?noredirect=1#comment284871_312785, could you edit your answer to indicate the solution? Specifically, it was to install the Roslyn SDK from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2ddb7240-5249-4c8c-969e-5d05823bcb89 and restart Visual Studio (maybe the extension was unnecessary?). Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer with Roslyn Sdk installation fix. But It's interesting what magically happened and fixed the issue. The only area I see to inspect is that you were using `GetCompilationAsync` while I have used the `GetSemanticModelAsync` to get the symbol information. May be Sdk have improved version of `GetCompilationAsync` but it's just a guess. Thank for the headsup.

Comment: You should really stop using `.Result()` to de-asynchronize your code.  Simply mark your calling method async and await those async calls.

Comment: @will this was a sample code so don't worry about it. yes.. you're right but what if one is not allowed to mark the method `async`.

Comment: @vendettamit Well if you can't do something correctly then you can't do it correctly, I suppose.  But that's not the situ, and I'd worry about it because someone is going to copypaste that code and I'll be wondering why visual studio has become so sluggish sometime in the future.  Also, FYI, typing `await` takes less keystrokes than `.Result()`, so lean towards that in your sample code to save yourself time :)

Comment: **tldr;** Marking async await doesn't really do special under the hood. If you look at the IL generated then it calls `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which is pretty much same as `.Result()`. The only difference is the failing exception type that these two throws.

Comment: Just think of the time when there was Task library released without `async-await` feature.

Comment: The SDK should have the same version as NuGet. If you can get a repro of your project where that didn't work, [file a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). My guess is MSBuildWorkspace wasn't working correctly, and that root cause hasn't been looked at here.

Comment: Invoking `SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(methodSymbol, solution).Result` throws an exception: `An item with the same key has already been added.`

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis version="2.6.1"