# How can I have all references of a method in Roslyn (method is called by other classes)?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Thanks to [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/), having access to .Net compiler, in our project [Gcop](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f082f20e-5123-4c0d-975a-0a17995d858b)  we need to have list of references where are calling a method.

VS IDE shows the reference places very suitable like this:

[image]

Actually I want to understand which class/name space and even assembly is calling my method by [Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/) C# syntax.

Currently I have access to MethodSymbol here :

```
var methodSymbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocation).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
```

what should I write to get access to references of this method?

//added recently for double check

```
 var solutionPath = Utilities.DteExtensions.SolutionFullPath;
 var msWorkspace = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
 var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result; 

 var result = new List<ReferenceLocation>();
 var refrences = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(methodSymbol, solution).Result;    

 foreach (var refernc in refrences)
  {
    foreach (var location in refernc.Locations)
     {
         result.Add(location);
     }
  }
///???????? why the result is empty ?
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `FindReferencesAsync()` methods on the [`SymbolFinder` class](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/FindSymbols/SymbolFinder_References.cs).

Comment: I've tried to find locations by SymbolFinder while each time returns nothing but there are couple of reference 
Please could you possibly answer me by Code? 
Also I tested 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340828/symbolfinder-findreferencesasync-doesnt-find-anything

this approach but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I tested this approach but is not quick , and can not find some syntax

```
 protected override void Analyze(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        NodeToAnalyze = context.Node;
        Method = context.Node as MethodDeclarationSyntax;

        // only public method should be checked
        if (!IsModifiersValid) return;

        var methodSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(Method) as IMethodSymbol;

        var solutionPath = Utilities.DteExtensions.SolutionFullPath;
        var msWorkspace = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
        var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;

        // looking in all projects inside of one solution
        var allDocumentsInEntireSolution = solution.Projects.SelectMany(it => it.Documents);

        //skip rule when in entire solution we have web form project             
        if (allDocumentsInEntireSolution.Any(x => x.Name == "Default.aspx.cs")) return;

        //Looking for all references            

        var refrencesFound = FindAllMethodReferences(Method.GetName(), solution);

        if (refrencesFound.Count() ==0)
            ReportDiagnostic(context, Method);
        else
        {
            var xyx = refrencesFound.Count();
        }

    }

    IEnumerable<ReferenceLocation> FindAllMethodReferences(string methodName, Solution solution)
    {
        IMethodSymbol methodSymbol = null;


        bool found = false;

        foreach (var project in solution.Projects)
        {
            foreach (var document in project.Documents)
            {
                var model = document.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;

                var methodInvocation = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result;

                try
                {
                    var nodes = methodInvocation.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>().Where(x => x.Expression.ToString().Contains(methodName));
                    foreach (var node in nodes)
                    {
                        if (node == null) continue;

                        var member = node?.Expression as MemberAccessExpressionSyntax;
                        if (member == null)
                            continue;

                        var name = member?.Name?.ToString();
                        if (name.IsEmpty()) continue;
                        if (name != methodName) continue;

                        methodSymbol = model.GetSymbolInfo(node).Symbol as IMethodSymbol;
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    // Swallow the exception of type cast. 
                    // Could be avoided by a better filtering on above linq.
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (found) break;
        }

        if (found == false) return Enumerable.Empty<ReferenceLocation>();
        if (methodSymbol == null) return Enumerable.Empty<ReferenceLocation>();

        var result = new List<ReferenceLocation>();
        var refrences = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(methodSymbol, solution).Result;

        foreach (var refernc in refrences)
        {
            foreach (var location in refernc.Locations)
            {
                result.Add(location);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to change following to make it work:

```
 var nodes = methodInvocation.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>()
   .Where(x => x.Expression.ToString().Contains(methodName));
```

To:

```
var nodes = new List<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();
foreach (var methodInvocationExpression in methodInvocation.DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>())
{
    if(methodInvocationExpression.DescendantNodes().OfType<MemberAccessExpressionSyntax>().Any(x => x.Name.Identifier.ValueText == methodName))
    {
        nodes.Add(methodInvocationExpression);
    }
}
```